# Setting up a non-emacs Common Lisp Dev Env for web application development?

Tags: common-lisp

I am trying to set up a Common Lisp Dev Env for web application development on my Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 64-bit box and I can't find a single decent guide that is targeted at noobs. The closest I came is with Peter Seibel's Lisp in a box but I detest Emacs with a passion and it seems to have older versions of SBCL and CLISP (which are my preferred CL implementations).

I do not want to use any of the commercial implementations. I am looking for a simple setup to write some very basic CRUD apps involving possibly hunchentoot, some framework like weblocks,CL-WHO, CL-SQl, sqlite or some datastores from the nosql family like mongo and couch..

Assuming, I go with either SBCL or CLISP on Linux, what is the best tool to manage packages and libraries? ASDF? I am looking for simplicity and consistency and I don't expect to use a ton of libs...

Answer (score 3):

There is an Eclipse plugin for Common Lisp called Cusp.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [clbuild](http://common-lisp.net/project/clbuild/). clbuild is a shell script helping with the download, compilation, an invocation of Common Lisp applications. It defaults to SBCL but otherwise tries to be somewhat independent of your local environment and it's widely used by Common Lisp developers.

Comment: Why would you want to use clbuild and not just [quicklisp](https://www.quicklisp.org/beta/) directly?